# SameSite=Strict Cookie not sent in safari when opening a new tab

Tags: cookies, safari

We are using cookies for some authentication purposes. When you open the WebApp, an XHR request (using `fetch()`) is done to an endpoint that generates a session cookie (amongst others). Then the app does multiple other XHR calls that use this session cookie.
These calls work absolutely fine.

However, when I open a link in a new tab (that - when logged in - forwards me to another URL to download a file), the cookies set to SameSite=Strict are not present.

the WebApp and the API both uses the same (sub-)domain let's say `app.example.com`

the image below shows the cookies that are present, when I let me show all cookies on the `app.example.com` main tab. the red-marked cookies are not present on a page opened in a new tab that points to `app.example.com/api/download...`

does anyone have an idea why that could happen and a better solution than just not setting `SameSite` if the browser is Safari?

[image: cookies]

Comment: I've noticed this in Chrome too